# trying to pull in the 2nd record in this query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following query which i am using to pull in data into an html page.  The url is something like example.com/sss.php?eventid=1111. So what the query does is it calls the event id and 1 record > than the event id.  How would i call the 1 record > than the event id so i can use it for a next button?

```
$eventid = _GET['eventid']

$resultnext = mysql_query("SELECT tblimage.*, events.* 
FROM events LEFT JOIN tblimage ON events.id_user = tblimage.userid 
WHERE event_id >= '$eventid' 
Order By event_id DESC 
LIMIT 2")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have it now if you have the following eventids: 1111, 1112, 1113, 1114, 1115, 1116, 1117.  With your query it would return 1116 and 1117. So, I think all you may need to do is change the `DESC` to `ASC`.  Doing so should produce 1111 and 1112.

**EDIT**, if you only need the next record for the button then use `LIMIT 1` and something like the following:

```
$eventid = _GET['eventid']

$resultnext = mysql_query("SELECT events.*, tblimage.*
                           FROM events LEFT JOIN tblimage 
                             ON events.id_user = tblimage.userid 
                           WHERE event_id > '$eventid' 
                           Order By event_id 
                           LIMIT 1");

$nResults = mysql_num_rows($resultnext);
if ($nResults > 0) {
  $row = mysql_fetch_row($resultnext);

  echo $row[0]; // 1112   would be what is returned if event id was the first field
  echo $row[1]; // would be what ever the second field is

  <a class="ui-pagination-next" 
            id="next" 
            data-ajax="true" 
            href="eventviewtester.php?eventid=<?php echo $row[0];?>"               
            style="display:none;"
  ></a> 
} else {
   //No Records were returned
}
```

I am not a PHP expert.  I just put together this code based on a search I did.  The `echo $row[0]` shows you how to get the individual data pieces.  Use that in conjunction with the button code.

Comment: ok, but how do i call the 1112 if im on record 1111 to use for a next button?

Comment: **@Steven**, I am not sure I follow you.  Do you mean you would prefer to have 1112 as the first record in the result?  See my edit for what I think you are needing

Comment: no, let me try to explain better.  Ok so the url has the 1111 in it so the data on the page needs to have the table details for that record. But i want to have a next button that would then pull in the 1112.  How would i set up the next button to read the 1112?

Comment: let me show you how I have the next button <a class="ui-pagination-next" id="next" data-ajax="true"  href="eventviewtester.php?eventid= <?php echo $next_event_id ;?>" style="display:none;"></a>

Comment: **@Steven**, I updated my answer to show how to get the next event id via php.

Comment: **@Steven**, I see that you have quotes around `$eventid` which would mean it is a string.  If it is not a string and instead a number then remove the quotes.

Comment: it works until i get to the last record, then it will give me a blank page.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47350/discussion-between-linger-and-steven)

Answer (score 2):

Change LIMIT 2 to the following:

```
LIMIT 2, 1
```